# Maintain aspect ratio of a div according to height

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, aspect-ratio

I have to **maintain the aspect ratio** of a div with respect to the height on window resize.

I can maintain the aspect ratio(x:y) with regard to the width(X%) using `padding-bottom;` or `padding-top;`.

So from the analogy, I tried using `padding-left;`

```
.wrapper{
   height: Y%,
   position: relative;
}

.wrapper:after{
   padding-left: Y(x/y)%;
   display:block;
}
```

But the percentage value of `padding-left` does not give any width to the wrapper.

How can I maintain the aspect ratio of that div according to its height?

Comment: Inshort you want a responsive div block keeping an aspect ratio of height and width?

Comment: yes, but w.r.t to height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As % padding/margin are calculated according to the width of the contrainer, you can't use the "padding technique" to maitain aspect ratio according to the height.

For a CSS solution, you will have to use `vh` units :

> **vh :** 1/100th of the height of the viewport.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

For browser support see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

---

**Example for a 1:1 aspect ratio :**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ALK9H/)**

*CSS*

```
div{
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is relative to the entire window. I hope there's a solution out there relative to the container...