# CSS square based on height

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

Is it possible to make a square `div` with css based on its **height** in ***pixels***?

This question is *similar* to [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789143/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-according-to-height) (marked as duplicate), but in this case I want height **to be set in pixel or any unit.**

When based on **width**, there is a simple solution :

```
.mydiv {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

But here **'height follows width'**. I'm looking for solution where **'width follows height'**. So if I would set **height** to 300px, **width** would follow it.

For now I'm doing it using javascript, updating on window resize. But I would like to find a CSS solution, thats why **I'm not looking for a javascript solution**

Here is a [playground](http://jsfiddle.net/h9ewm/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the new `viewport size units`

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h9ewm/2/)

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width:100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**Support is effectively IE9 and up**](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

Comment: That's not answering his question. As far as I know, he wanted to know if it is possible to make the height influence the width in a specific way. Which, by the way, is something I'd also love to know.

Comment: @sb this is the answer to the question if you look at the demo, the aspect ratio of the div is maintained according to it's height.

Comment: But only for this very specific example. Edit: By the way, I'm not trying to be mean or anything. I'm just saying that the answer I'm hoping for (and I guess others too) is still out there :)

Comment: @sb. so... it answers the question...

Comment: Don't think so! I doubt that he's trying to fill a square viewport like this.

Comment: The problem here is that vh is relative to screen (resolution) size, so it would be hard (and requireing js) to make like height: 150px; At the end - I think this solution is working indeed, but vh unit makes it not so useful (for example comparing to solution based on width)

Comment: I've edited question so I want height to be set in pixels or any unit that makes this answer not matching. Thanks anyway.