# Maintain aspect ratio of a div with dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a square div by **pure CSS** what it's `height` is dynamic and it's `width` will scale base on `height`.
As we can see in the snipet below, the `container` height is dynamic base on its content. 
The red `square` take full height of the `container` and the width should be equal `height`.
I know we can [maintain aspect ratio of a div base on its width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) but i can not find a way when the `height` is **dynamic**.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much! 
**Note that:** The height is dynamic so [the solution with `vh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23789270/4254681) did not work and the snipet is just a playground.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative; 
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  background-color: red;
  
  width: 100px /*Hmm its just a dummy value*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    I'm a dynamic content
  </div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use css's calc function. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Comment: @LucasRosenberger: I know `calc()` but how do i use it to caculate width base on height?

Comment: Sorry missunderstood your question. I think you'll need to use js for this usecase.

Comment: @LucasRosenberger: Ya, thank you! I am just finding a pure css solution because perfomance reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one other solution:

We can make an inner div inside the main `.square` div inherits its parent height.

Then, if we rotate that inner div, its height now becomes its width. So all we've got to do at this point, is to hide the overflow from the parent div, and apply some translation so it ends at the correct position.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.square>div {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(100%, 0%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content">
    <textarea> I'm a dynamic content</textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat. In Firefox there's a white line to the right of the red square though.

Comment: @MrLister ah? I made it on FF (58.b) and do not notice it. Your zoom levels are at 100%?

Comment: Yes, tested on different versions. It's OK in Chrome.

Comment: @MrLister How weird, I tested on stable branch too, and on Nightly at different zoom levels, and can't reproduce this issue... (ran on a non-retina osX) That would be a bug in FF I guess. Can you try without the textarea?

Comment: Nice solution. I tested it in Chrome and FF. And it works fine. Just wait some hours and i will acept your answer if no one have better solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

Note that I added `contenteditable` to the content div, so that you can type in the snippet to add lines of text to see the effect. Of course this isn't necessary in your version.

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative; 
}

.square {
  position: absolute; z-index:-1;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
  background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsIAAA7CARUoSoAAAAANSURBVBhXY/jPwPAfAAUAAf+mXJtdAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  background-size:contain; background-position:100% 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content" contenteditable="true">
    I'm a dynamic content
  </div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

The trick is that the background is now a red square (it's a 1×1 image) which is sized with `contain`. This is not possible with `background-color` I'm afraid.

Comment: @VXp True, but from the question I gathered that the OP just needed a red square, period. If the OP has other needs, they should mention so; then I'll see what I can do.

Comment: well, to be fair, the OP clearly state that he `wanted to create a square div`, nice trick though

Comment: @MrLister: It is a really clever answer. But it is not what i want. My main purpose is maintain aspect ratio of the div base on its height. Nice trick but it did not solve the main problem. Anyway, thank you!